# Bootstrap 4, blue horizontal line on navbar under list on dark background

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

How to remove this blue horizontal like which appears on nav bar under the list looking like separating two things on dark background, but don't know what or how did it appear there. Code is written with bootstrap 4, using some other fonts[image]

Also how do you make search bar actually work with this code, because for me it didn't seem to work

```css
    @import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
    body {
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        background: #fafafa;
    }
    
    p {
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 1.7em;
        color: #999;
    }
    
    a,
    a:hover,
    a:focus {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    
    .navbar {
        padding: 15px 10px;
        background: #fff;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    
    .navbar-btn {
        box-shadow: none;
        outline: none !important;
        border: none;
    }
    
    .line {
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
        margin: 40px 0;
    }
    
    /* ---------------------------------------------------
        SIDEBAR STYLE
    ----------------------------------------------------- */
    
    
    
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 250px;
        max-width: 250px;
        background: #343a40;
        color: #fff;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    
    
    #sidebar ul.components {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
    }
    
    #sidebar ul p {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        display: block;
    }
    
    #sidebar ul li a:hover {
        color: #343a40;
        background: #fff;
    }
    
    #sidebar ul li.active>a,
    a[aria-expanded="true"] {
        color: #fff;
        background: #f0ad4e;
    }
    
    a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown-toggle::after {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 20px;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    
    ul ul a {
        font-size: 0.9em !important;
        padding-left: 30px !important;
        background: #292b2c;
    }
    
    
    
    
    /* ---------------------------------------------------
        MEDIAQUERIES
    ----------------------------------------------------- */
    
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        #sidebar {
            margin-left: -250px;
        }
        #sidebar.active {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        #sidebarCollapse span {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <div class="container-flex">
            <!-- navbar top-->
                      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
    
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                                </li>
                              <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                              <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <!-- Sidebar -->
                <nav class="" id="sidebar">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
    
                  
                </nav>
            <div class="container-flex d-flex" style="width: 40%">
                <div class="col">
                <!--main page-->
                <p>Main Content</p>
                </div>
    
            </div>
            <div class="container-flex d-flex" style="width: 40%">
    
                <div class="col bg-dark">
                  <!--Code Editor-->
                  <p>Code Editor</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    
    
          </div>
      </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is here:

```
#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}
```

You just need to remove the border-bottom.

```
#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Check the code below, working :)

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */



#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #343a40;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}


#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;

}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #343a40;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #f0ad4e;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #292b2c;
}




/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="container-flex">
        <!-- navbar top-->
                  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">

<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
            <nav class="" id="sidebar">
                <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>


            </nav>
        <div class="container-flex d-flex" style="width: 40%">
            <div class="col">
            <!--main page-->
            <p>Main Content</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="container-flex d-flex" style="width: 40%">

            <div class="col bg-dark">
              <!--Code Editor-->
              <p>Code Editor</p>
            </div>
        </div>


      </div>
  </div>
```